# How to find the Union between two priority queues?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have found the intersection and the difference between two priority queues, but I am having trouble figuring out how to find the union between the two. I feel like id be able to do it with arrays but I am struggling to find a way with priority queues (The assignment requires it)

```
enter code here   public static PriorityQueue<String> intersection(PriorityQueue<String> q1, PriorityQueue<String> q2){
    PriorityQueue<String> q3 = new PriorityQueue<>();
    for(String string:q1){
        if(q2.contains(string)){
            q3.add(string);
        }
    }
    return q3;
}
enter code here public static PriorityQueue<String> difference(PriorityQueue<String> q1, PriorityQueue<String> intersectionQueue){
    PriorityQueue<String> q3 = new PriorityQueue<>();
    for(String string:q1){
     if(intersectionQueue.contains(string)){

     }else{
         q3.add(string);
     }
    }
    return q3;
}
```

I am just looking for hints here not a solution, really need help

Comment: What's the expected output for [2, 2, 2] and [2, 2]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Warning:* You are applying Set semantics to non-Set collection objects, so results are arbitrary if the input PriorityQueues contain duplicate elements.

Assuming they don't, the other problem is that your code is using the *O(n)* `contains()` method, so the operation is *O(m*n)*.

For better performance, you should use a real [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

---

The standard [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) classes, including [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html), all implement [`retainAll(c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-), which is the equivalent of a "set intersection". The implementation uses `c.contains(o)`, so `c` should be a [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) object, resulting in *O(m+n)* performance.

```
public static PriorityQueue<String> intersection(PriorityQueue<String> q1, PriorityQueue<String> q2) {
    PriorityQueue<String> q3 = new PriorityQueue<>(q1);
    q3.retainAll(new HashSet<>(q2));
    return q3;
}
```

---

The standard `Collection` classes, including `PriorityQueue`, all implement `removeAll(c)`, which is the equivalent to an "asymmetric set difference". The implementation uses `c.contains()`, so `c` should be a `HashSet` object, resulting in *O(m+n)* performance.

```
public static PriorityQueue<String> difference(PriorityQueue<String> q1, PriorityQueue<String> intersectionQueue) {
    PriorityQueue<String> q3 = new PriorityQueue<>(q1);
    q3.removeAll(new HashSet<>(intersectionQueue));
    return q3;
}
```

---

The standard `Set` classes all implement [`addAll(c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-), which is the equivalent to a "set union". Using a `HashSet` results in *O(m+n)* performance.

```
public static PriorityQueue<String> union(PriorityQueue<String> q1, PriorityQueue<String> q2) {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(q1);
    set.addAll(q2);
    return new PriorityQueue<>(set);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I don't know how to give you a reputation point, i don't come here often.

Answer (score 0):

Union? This is relatively simple, right? Just add all the items of two queues into resultant queue. That's it.

```
public static PriorityQueue<String> union(PriorityQueue<String> q1, PriorityQueue<String> q2){
    PriorityQueue<String> q3 = new PriorityQueue<>();
    q3.addAll(q1);
    q3.addAll(q2);
    return q3;
}
```

**Update**

If you don't want to allow duplicates

```
public static PriorityQueue<String> union(PriorityQueue<String> q1, PriorityQueue<String> q2){
    Set<String> hashSet = new HashSet<>(q1);
    hashSet.addAll(q2);
    return new PriorityQueue<>(hashSet);
}
```

Comment: My understanding is that the OP is avoiding duplicates. And as far as I know, queues don't discard duplicates like sets do.

Comment: avoiding duplicates? For example: union of [2, 2, 2] and [2, 2] will yield [2, 2, 2] or [2, 2] or [2]?

Comment: From what I see in the question, it seems that it would be `[2]`. I don't know it definitely, I just think that's the intention.

Comment: Hey kaidul, I cannot do that because I cannot have duplicates

Comment: Its frustrating, i would be able to solve this very easily with arrays but i am struggling to figure out a way with quese, very tricky

Comment: Also sorry for 3 consecutive comments but here are my strings for queue 1 queue1.offer("George");
        queue1.offer("Jim");
        queue1.offer("John");
        queue1.offer("Blake");
        queue1.offer("Kevin");
        queue1.offer("Michael");     And queue 2   queue2.offer("George");
        queue2.offer("Katie");
        queue2.offer("Kevin");
        queue2.offer("Michelle");
        queue2.offer("Ryan");